# How to get what bundled products a simple product was sold in

Tags: bundled-product, sales-order, grouped-products

I am trying to find out, for a product, for a date range, the following

1. How many times was it sold individually
2. How many times was it sold as part of another product ( bundled or grouped ) and what that product is.

I think I can use the `$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')` but am not sure how to interrogate what I am getting back from that collection in PHPStorm.  Would someone be able to help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

1) For getting the details about the count of the product sold you can easily get from the sales and order related tables.
2) For group products I think you are bound and required to manage different tables and required to use join query to have combination of results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  So then to get totals I'll foreach over the $collection but how can I see what columns are in that collection?  I spent time yesterday trying to see what Sales/Order returns but to no avail, any suggestions?

Comment: If u want to see the collection's value you can see it by using print_r. If u you are knwing then collection is always an array so by printing the values using that you will get alk the columns of the db. Try this out.